# Count rows for categories group by months and years

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have this table called Services

```
Service,  Start_date,   End_date
Service1  2017-08-18    2019-03-13
Service2  2013-02-02    NULL
Service3  2015-05-03    2016-12-14
```

What I'm looking for is to get a list of all de services, the count of clients(rows) which had that service for each month / year.

The result I want would be something like this

```
Service,  Year-Month,   Count
Service1   2017-01        4
Service2   2017-02        3
Service1   2018-01        7
```

All my tries ended up with incorect data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*Later edit:*
The best I got to, which is nowhere near the desired result is this:

```
SELECT count (*), Service , start
FROM (
SELECT Service, month(Start_date) as start, month(End_date)  
FROM Services
group by month(Start_date), month(End_date),Service
) as data
group by start,Service
order by start asc
```

For every month of the year I want to know how many clients had a certain service active, meaning that it was started before that point in time and it did not end yet. And so on for every month of the year, starting with 2017

Comment: _All my tries ended up with incorect data..._ Could you show us at least 1 of your best approaches? Also tell us what logic is behind that. Your expected result doens't make any sense compared to ypour input data

Comment: Suppose service 1 is offered from 2019-03-01 to 2019-10-01. Then will the count of Service 1 be positive for the month, say, 2019-05?

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes, it will be counted as being active because it's between the start date and the end date.

Comment: This wouldn't be a simple query then. You'll have to loop over all the months b/w start date and end date, and create an entry for the Service. Then you can apply the aggregate functions on top of this view.